# JMS queue not found exception

Tags: bpel

Oi
I have a bpel process that puts messages in a jms queue and I need to do some specific work if the insertion on the queue fails for some reason.
To test that i disabled the insertion on the EM console but when the bpel tries to insert an exception is raised and i can't catch it.
Any work around for my problem?

This is my response

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <tracking:faultId xmlns:tracking="http://oracle.soa.tracking.core.TrackingProperty">470018</tracking:faultId>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
            <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Exception occurred when binding was invoked. Exception occurred during invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of Reference operation 'Produce_Message' failed due to: ERRJMS_PROVIDER_ERR. ERRJMS_PROVIDER_ERR. Unable to produce message due to JMS provider internal error. Please examine the log file to determine the problem. ". The invoked JCA adapter raised a resource exception. Please examine the above error message carefully to determine a resolution.</faultstring>
            <faultactor/>
            <detail>
                <exception>Failed to send message to the destination SRVMEModule!SRVS04: Destination is suspended</exception>
            </detail>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fault looks like a standard binding fault which could be easly caught and handled. Put your jms insert activity inside a scope and you should be able to define error handler(catch all) on the scope level.